# Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 - team explorer for microsoft visual studio 2015 update 3 ctp1 error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am having a trouble with installing Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.
It keeps failing to install Team Explorer.
[HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3zpyjxuv199y91p/dd_vs_community_20161124123823.log?dl=0) is log.

(I am using Window 7 because my computer's Mother Board does not support Windows 10.)

Comment: Should this question be posted to superuser? I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this link for a possible solution:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs-knownissues/vs2015-update3

Comment: I tried but.. still having same problem. Visual Studio keeps saying it conflict with previous settings when I do Update3 solution.

Comment: try reinstalling the VS2015 or if you still cant, try downloading an older version since there is not much difference between the versions. I recommend 2012

Comment: maybe VS2015 are not well compatible with Windows 7. I will try to install 2012.

Comment: I have had the same problem when i was installing the VS2016 in windows 7 which gave me a bunch of weird errors because of the uncompatible os and the required "Microsoft Edge". Anyways, i hope VS2012 works fine for you. Good Luck

Comment: I solved problem by installing visual studio 2012 express.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have an early version of Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 **CTP** installed. Try to uninstall this first as these prerelease versions does not handle upgrade that well.

To my knowledge Visual Studio 2015 should work just fine on Window 7.